# Vector to Scalar

Tags: matlab

I have a simple problem that I can't seem to figure out a simple solution for ...

I have a vector x

`x = [1, 2, 3, 4]`

I'd like to turn that vector into a scalar where the scalar is comprised of the values of x.

for example:

```
>> y = compressvec(x)
   y = 
       1234
```

It'd be nice if the solution also worked on arrays treating each row as its own vector

for example :

`x = [1, 2, 3, 4; 5, 6, 7, 8]`

```
>> y = compressvect(x)
   y = 
       1234
       5678

 >> size(y)
    ans =
         2     1
```

Comment: Are entries of `x` guaranteed to be less than 10?

Comment: yes ... all values should be treated as 0-9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some ways to do it:

- Convert to characters, then interpret as a base-10 number:

  ```
  y = base2dec(char(x+'0'), 10);
  ```
- Similar, via cell array of character vectors:

  ```
  y = str2double(cellstr(char(x+'0')));
  ```
- Direct arithmetic approach using matrix multiplication:

  ```
  y = x * 10.^(size(x,2)-1:-1:0).';
  ```
- Similar, using element-wise multiplication with broadcast:

  ```
  y = sum(bsxfun(@times, x, 10.^(size(x,2)-1:-1:0)), 2);
  ```

Comment: slick solution!

Comment: Just to add to this a bit, if you have many columns then the last two approaches may not be the best, as you may lose precision.  If you do need to go the route of strings, in recent MATLAB versions you can simply do `join(string(x), "")`;

Comment: @CKT Thanks! I'm still not very fond of the new `string` data type :-) As for the loss of precision, you are totally right, but then the other approaches lose precision too, as would any other method that produces a `double`

Comment: Yes, you're definitely right, but if you're in a regime where you can have precision loss, the string method will be guaranteed to give you the minimal loss.  This is because the conversion to double will necessarily give you the closest representable number to your string, whereas the multiplication method may lose precision in intermediate calculations as well.  Example:
`>> x = 1:14;
>> format hex;
>> x * 10.^(size(x,2)-1:-1:0).'
ans =
   42a674e79fc3f000
>> double(join(string(x),""))
ans =
   43b12210f4b2d231
>> 1234567891011121314
ans =
   43b12210f4b2d231`

Comment: @LuisMendo, is there anything particular about the string data type that you're not fond about or is it just because it's newer?

Comment: @matlabbit I find it redundant (char vectors were/are just fine), and confusing (char vectors were informally called strings). Also the syntax seems awkard to me, but I guess I'll get used with time